# Dynamic text in JSP file based on URL

Tags: javascript, jsp

How to dynamically add text in JSP file based on URL?

For example,

If this is the URL : [www.example.com/containerA/welcome](http://www.example.com/containerA/welcome)

Page content should have this text:
`Welcome to Container A!`

If this is the URL : [www.example.com/containerB/welcome](http://www.example.com/containerB/welcome)

Page content should have this text:
`Welcome to Container B!`

I'm looking for something to conditinally display text in `<p> ... </p>` based on a string in URL.

Comment: You could use URL rewriting to turn that URL into `/welcome.jsp?container=containerA`, then use basic parameter processing.

Comment: How can I communicate between URL and body of a JSP file?

Comment: You can use js ?